# Sum of all products of numbers by taking one or more from $A$

Tags: proof-verification, summation

Consider $A=(1,2,3,4......10)$.Find the sum of all products of numbers by taking one or more from $A$?

But calculation seems to be quite tricky.

I was thinking of using equation:

$(x-1)(x-2)...(x-10)=x^{10}-$ (Sum of roots)$x^9$+......+(Product of roots) and then putting $x=-1$

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  approach is fine.

> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> (x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)|_{x=-1}&=(-2)(-3)\cdots(-n-1)\\
> &=(-1)^n(n+1)!
> \end{align*}
>
> the  result  is 
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(n+1)!-1}
> \end{align*}
>   We   subtract $1$ to respect the factor $x^n$ evaluated at $x=-1$ which does not count.